# Running Scala tests automatically either after test change or tested class change

Tags: testing, scala

I'm wondering if there is any solution to let Scala tests run automatically upon change of test class itself or class under the test (just to test automatically pairs Class <---> ClassTest) would be a good start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[sbt](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/) can help you with this. After you setup project, just run

```
~test
```

`~` means continuous execution. So that **sbt** will watch file system changes and when changes are detected it recompiles changed classes and tests your code. [`~testQuick`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#testQuick) can be even more suitable for you, because it runs only tests, that were changed (including test class and all it's transitive dependencies). You can read more about this here:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/TriggeredExecution

http://php.jglobal.com/blog/?p=363

By the way, `~` also works with other tasks like `~run`.